# PySpark regex to get value between a string and hyphen

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I am trying to extract the number between the string “line_number:” and hyphen. I am struggling with generating a regex/substring for the same in PySpark.
Below is my input data in a column called “whole_text”. The string “line_number:” will always be in each row followed by the number and hyphen. Is there any way I can find the text “line_number:” and first hyphen after that and extract the number in between?

The output should be 121, 3112 and so on in a new column.

Please help.

```
text:ABC12637-XYZ  line_number:121-ABC:JJ11
header:3AXYZ166-LMN  line_number:3112-GHI:3A1
```

Answer (score 1):

Some minimal example code would be useful to replicate your problem..

Here is how I'd solve this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([("""
text:ABC12637-XYZ  line_number:121-ABC:JJ11
header:3AXYZ166-LMN  line_number:3112-GHI:3A1
""",)], ['str'])

df.select("str", F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(str, r'line_number:(\d+)-', 1)").alias('extracted')).show()
```

Which produces:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|                 str|  extracted|
+--------------------+-----------+
|\ntext:ABC12637-X...|[121, 3112]|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Update:

```
 df.withColumn('extracted_regex', F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(str, r'line_number:(\d+)-', 1)")).show()
+--------------------+---------------+
|                 str|extracted_regex|
+--------------------+---------------+
|\ntext:ABC12637-X...|    [121, 3112]|
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Using Python 3.12 and Spark 3.5

```
>>> spark.version
'3.5.0'
```

Comment: I am getting below error while trying to run: 

`E   Literals of type 'R' are currently not supported.(line 1, pos 32)
E   
E   == SQL ==
E   regexp_extract_all(detail_text, r'line_number:(\d+)-', 1)
E   --------------------------------^^^
`

this is my code: 

`df.withColumn('extracted_regex', F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(detail_text, r'line_number:(\d+)-', 1)"))`

Comment: It still works on me even if I use `df.withColumn` (updated answer to contain this)